# Invoking Perl debugger so that it runs until first breakpoint

Tags: perl, debugging

When I invoke my Perl debugger with `perl -d myscript.pl`, the debugger starts, but it does not execute any code until I press `n` (next) or `c` (continue).

Is there anyway to invoke the debugger and have it run through the code by default until it hits a breakpoint?

If so, is there any statement that I can use in my code as a breakpoint to have the debugger stop when it hits it?

### Update:

Here is what I have in my `.perldb` file:

```
print "Reading ~/.perldb options.\n";
push @DB::typeahead, "c";
parse_options("NonStop=1");
```

Here is my `hello_world.pl` file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello world.\n"; 
$DB::single=1;
print "How are you?";
```

Here is the debugging session from running: `perl -d hello_world.pl`:

```
Reading ~/.perldb options.
Hello world
main::(hello_world.pl:6):       print "How are you?";
auto(-1)  DB<1> c
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.  
  DB<1> v
9563    9564    
9565    sub at_exit {
9566==>     "Debugged program terminated.  Use `q' to quit or `R' to restart.";
9567    }
9568    
9569    package DB;    # Do not trace this 1; below!
  DB<1>
```

In other words, my debugger skips `print "How are you?"`, and instead stops once the program finishes, which is not what I want.

What I want is have the debugger run my code **without stopping anywhere** (nor at the beginning, nor at the end of my script), **unless** I explicitly have a `$DB::single=1;` statement, in which case I would like it to stop before running the next line. Any ways to do this?

For reference, I am using:

```
$perl --version 

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 1 (v5.14.1) built for x86_64-linux
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put

```
$DB::single = 1;
```

before any statement to set a permanent breakpoint in your code.
This works with compile-time code, too, and may be the only good way to set a breakpoint during the compile phase.

---

To have the debugger automatically start your code, you can manipulate the `@DB::typeahead` array in either a `.perldb` file or in a compile-time (`BEGIN`) block in your code. For example:

```
# .perldb file
push @DB::typeahead, "c";
```

or

```
BEGIN { push @DB::typeahead, "p 'Hello!'", "c" }
...
$DB::single = 1;
$x = want_to_stop_here();
```

There is also a `"NonStop"` option that you could set in `.perldb` or in the `PERLDB_OPTS` environment variable:

```
PERLDB_OPTS=NonStop perl -d myprogram.pl
```

All of this (and much more) is discussed deep in the bowels of [`perldebug`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perldebug) and [`perl5db.pl`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5db.pl)

### Update:

To address the issues raised in the most recent update. Use the following in `./perldb`:

```
print "Reading ~/.perldb options.\n";
push @DB::typeahead, "c";
parse_options("inhibit_exit=0");
```

Comment: I have the following in my `.perldb`: `push @DB::typeahead, "c"; parse_options("NonStop=1");`, and then `DB::single = 1;` in my code right before a print statement. Yet, the debugger seems to ignore this and stop at the end of my script. Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: It could be caused be your program never reaching that statement.

Comment: Also, using both `NonStop=1` and `@typeahead=("c")` is like hitting "c" twice, which may not be what you meant.

Comment: Thanks @mob. I updated the original post. I am still not getting it right.

Comment: I just added a new bit to your answer to address the last question I raised.

Answer (score 2):

Also check out [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/module/Enbugger). And while on the topic of debuggers, see [Devel::Trepan](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aTrepan) which also works with Enbugger.